# I want to cumulate a list of string values by date

Tags: r, cumulative-sum

I have column A, which is a date and B which is a string value.

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/02/23 | apple |
| 2 | 01/02/23 | pear |
| 3 | 01/02/23 | apple |
| 4 | 02/02/23 | apple |
| 3 | 02/02/23 | apple |
| 3 | 02/02/23 | banana |
| 3 | 02/02/23 | banana |
| 3 | 02/02/23 | apple |

I would like the output to be a list on unique dates, with cumulation day on day of the string values in B.

Like so

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/02/23 | apple |
|  |  | pear |
| 1 | 02/02/23 | apple |
|  |  | pear |
|  |  | banana |

Thank you in advance!!!!

I've tried basic cumulations but cant seem to get to the desired result when i use string value not numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update removed first answer: We can do it using `accumulate` together with `union` and some data tweaking:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) 

df %>% 
  arrange(A) %>% 
  mutate(cumulative = accumulate(B, ~union(.x, .y))) %>% 
  reframe(B = last(cumulative), .by=A) %>% 
  unnest(B) %>% 
  mutate(A = ifelse(row_number() != 1, "", A), .by=A)
```

```
  A      B
1 1  apple
2     pear
3 2  apple
4     pear
5   banana
```

Comment: how do i then keep pear as well as apple and banana on 2/02/23 ! thank you for the help btw!

Comment: wow amazing ! thank you for the help, will return to you if i have any issues :)